# React Unable to Change Checkboxes

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

When I click on the checkboxes coming from an array with field isChecked nothing happens. the handleChange() apparently not working. Everything seems to map ok, because the checkboxes that are set to true or false initially  show correctly. None of the fields showed up checked until I added isChecked= {network[i].isChecked}. But now i can't check or uncheck.  Where did I mess up?

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import NetworkArray from './components/NetworkArray';
import {network} from './NetworkData'
import './App.css';
import 'tachyons';

class App extends Component  {

    constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
    network: network,
    searchfield:'',

}
this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);

}


handleChange(id) {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    const updatedNetwork = prevState.network.map(netw => {
      if (netw.id === id) {
        netw.isChecked = !netw.isChecked
      }
      return netw
    })
    return {
      network:updatedNetwork
    }
  })
}
render() {
  const filteredNetwork = this.state.network.filter(netw => {
    return netw.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase())
  })

  return (

      <div>

         <NetworkArray 
             network={filteredNetwork}
             handleChange = {this.handleChange}  />
      </div> 

    )
}

}
export default App;
```

CardComponent

```
import React from 'react';

const Card = (props) => {

    return(
        <div className = 'bg-light-green dib br3 pa3 ma2 grow  shadow-5'>

        <div>
            <h3>{props.name}</h3>
            <p>{props.company}</p> 
            <p>{props.phone}</p>
            <p>{props.email}</p>
            <p>{props.city}</p> 

         </div>
         <div> 
            My Network
            <input className ="largeCheckbox"
                type = "checkbox"
                checked={props.isChecked}
                onChange={()=> props.handleChange(props.id)}
                    /> 
            </div> 
         </div> 

        )
}

export default Card;
```

NetworkArray.js

```
    import Card from './Card';

    const NetworkArray = ({network,handleChange}) => {
        const cardComponent = network.map((user,i) => {
            return(
            <Card 
                key = {network[i].id}
                name = {network[i].firstName + ' ' + network[i].lastName} 
                company = {network[i].company}
                phone= {network[i].phone}
                email={network[i].email}
                city = {network[i].city}
                isChecked= {network[i].isChecked}
                handleChange={handleChange}

                />

                        )
        })
            return ( 
                    <div> 

                     {cardComponent}


                    </div> 
                )
    }

    export default NetworkArray;
```

Comment: You call `props.handleChange(props.id)` in the `Card` component, but you don't appear to be providing an `id` to `Card` in `NetworkArray`.

Comment: Not sure how I would add that? The id is called in the handleChange function.

Comment: Just add `id = {network[i].id}` as a prop when you're useing `Card`, that might make it all work

Comment: Wow that seemed to work!  Thanks!

Comment: Okay cool, I'll add an actual answer to this question, would appreciate it you mark it as correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an `id` prop to your `Card` component so that you have something to pass to `props.handleChange`:

```
<Card
  id={network[i].id}
  key={network[i].id}
  name={network[i].firstName + ' ' + network[i].lastName} 
  company={network[i].company}
  phone={network[i].phone}
  email={network[i].email}
  city={network[i].city}
  isChecked={network[i].isChecked}
  handleChange={handleChange}
/>
```